# Comparing two columns and printing out the difference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two big columns that I'm comparing in Excel. I want to print out the values that column A has from Column B.

This is what I've tried: `=ISNA(MATCH(A3,$A$:$D$28309,0))`

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
A          B          B
B          C          C
C          E
D          E
A          E
```

Comment: Can you share the expected result, it's unclear from your question.

Comment: @MarkS. - I think Column C is the expected result.

Comment: So the expected Result would be Column C. Where It prints the values that in Column B are in Column A

Comment: @Kingjohn thanks for your response, I believe I solved your question, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A5,B:B,0)))
```

[image]

---

If not then INDEX(AGGREGATE()).  Put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A5)/ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A5,B:B,0)),ROW(ZZ1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: So I have 20000 rows. Here is what I put: =FILTER(A1:A283079,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A283079,D:D,0)))

Comment: It's saying invalid function

Comment: Then you do not have `FILTER` and will need to do the AGGREGATE method.  But be warned, that many will cause a burden on the calcs.  May be okay for you, but you may want to consider vba

Comment: This function is not printing anything: =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A2:A283079)/ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A283079,D:D,0)),ROW(ZZ1))),"")

Comment: I'm not sure what ZZ1 are suppose to do.

Comment: Then it is either not finding matches, or the calc is still going.  Remove the `IFERROR(...,"")` wrapper and see what happens.  But with that many vba will probably be your only option.  ZZ1 is just a counter that changes as it is copied down.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original range is `A1:B6` As you drag this formula down column C it will list all of the common values in the order of the first column then produce a `#NUM!` error when it runs out of matches. You can use an `IFERROR` formula to change the result to something else in those cases.

The size of the column don't need to match either.

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$6, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6, $A$2:$A$6), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$6),ROW($A$2:$A$6)), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

Make sure to hit `CTRL` + `Shift` + `Enter` as this is an array formula.